# How to do the grouping in k-map in java?

Tags: java

I am not that good in java.. I am working in a project,in my project the program should draw the k-map,I used labels to draw it, its works good.. I just want to know if there any easy way to do the grouping by changing the background color of the label..? the problem is I don't have any efficient way.. the only way comes to me is to use all probabilities that may occur to group the ones and put it in if statement !!(I know it will be aloooot of probabilities especially when the number of variables is four) :(

like this (I will not post it all):

```
if(lbl1.getText().equals("1")&& lbl2.getText().equals("")&&lbl3.getText().equals("")&& lbl4.getText().equals("")&&lbl5.getText().equals("")&& lbl6.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl7.getText().equals("")&& lbl8.getText().equals("")&&lbl9.getText().equals("")&& lbl10.getText().equals("")&&lbl11.getText().equals("")&& lbl12.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl13.getText().equals("")&& lbl14.getText().equals("")&&lbl15.getText().equals("")&&lbl16.getText().equals("")){
        lbl1.setOpaque(true);
        lbl1.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
 else if(lbl1.getText().equals("")&& lbl2.getText().equals("1")&&lbl3.getText().equals("")&& lbl4.getText().equals("")&&lbl5.getText().equals("")&& lbl6.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl7.getText().equals("")&& lbl8.getText().equals("")&&lbl9.getText().equals("")&& lbl10.getText().equals("")&&lbl11.getText().equals("")&& lbl12.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl13.getText().equals("")&& lbl14.getText().equals("")&&lbl15.getText().equals("")&&lbl16.getText().equals("")){
        lbl2.setOpaque(true);
        lbl2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
else if(lbl1.getText().equals("")&& lbl2.getText().equals("")&&lbl3.getText().equals("")&& lbl4.getText().equals("")&&lbl5.getText().equals("1")&& lbl6.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl7.getText().equals("")&& lbl8.getText().equals("")&&lbl9.getText().equals("")&& lbl10.getText().equals("")&&lbl11.getText().equals("")&& lbl12.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl13.getText().equals("")&& lbl14.getText().equals("")&&lbl15.getText().equals("")&&lbl16.getText().equals("")){
        lbl5.setOpaque(true);
        lbl5.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
  else if(lbl1.getText().equals("")&& lbl2.getText().equals("")&&lbl3.getText().equals("")&& lbl4.getText().equals("")&&lbl5.getText().equals("")&& lbl6.getText().equals("1")
            &&lbl7.getText().equals("")&& lbl8.getText().equals("")&&lbl9.getText().equals("")&& lbl10.getText().equals("")&&lbl11.getText().equals("")&& lbl12.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl13.getText().equals("")&& lbl14.getText().equals("")&&lbl15.getText().equals("")&&lbl16.getText().equals("")){
        lbl6.setOpaque(true);
        lbl6.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
  else if(lbl1.getText().equals("1")&& lbl2.getText().equals("1")&&lbl3.getText().equals("")&& lbl4.getText().equals("")&&lbl5.getText().equals("")&& lbl6.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl7.getText().equals("")&& lbl8.getText().equals("")&&lbl9.getText().equals("")&& lbl10.getText().equals("")&&lbl11.getText().equals("")&& lbl12.getText().equals("")
            &&lbl13.getText().equals("")&& lbl14.getText().equals("")&&lbl15.getText().equals("")&&lbl16.getText().equals("")){
        lbl1.setOpaque(true);
        lbl1.setBackground(Color.blue);
        lbl2.setOpaque(true);
        lbl2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
```

Comment: This is really poor implementation. You should group each JLabel in a list for example, and iterate over this list

Comment: Oh my, an array might help here

Comment: Grouping is to identify a key and use that key to map a collection associated with it.

Comment: any other suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an array (or list) of all 16 labels named `labels`, something like:

```
for (final JLabel label : labels) {
    // reset others?
    if ("1".equals(label.getText()) {
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.blue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to ask.. if I want to add some conditions .. how can I do it ? for example I want to write if the two labels near each other it will color with a specific color and other labels that are also near to each other with another color? and if three labels continuously con not have same color!!